# UINavigationController Back Button Pop View Animation on iOS6

Tags: ipad, ios6

I didn't add any Transition animation on Back Button.

My Code is really simple like below,

```
 categorySubListViewController *categorySub =[[categorySubListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"categorySubListViewController" bundle:nil];

 categorySub.detailViewController=self.detailViewController;

 [self.navigationController pushViewController:categorySub animated:YES];
```

However , popview controller animation is wrong and it showing like below (up to down animation) .

[image]

It should be right to left animation .

Is there any wrong in my code or iOS 6 problem ?

Working well on iPhone iOS 6 , iPad iOS 6 Portrait.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fixed.

The problem is

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

}
```

It should be

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;

}
```